# when to use an alternative Python distribution?

Tags: python, distribution, cpython, pypy

I have been programming in Python for a few years now and have always used CPython without thinking about it. The books and documentation I have read always refer to CPython too.

When does it make sense to use an alternative distribution (PyPy, Stackless, etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need native interfacing with the JVM, use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).

When you need native interfacing with the .Net platform, or want to use Winforms, use [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython).

If you need the latest version, cross-OS support, make use of existing C-based modules existing only for [CPython](http://www.python.org), the use it.

If you are thinking into proposing a functional PEP, going the Pypy route could be useful.

If you need to do something that Python makes hard (i.e. microthreading), you could go the [Stackless](http://www.stackless.com/) way, or any other language (Haskel, etc.).

---

The alternative implementations are *always* behind CPython, most now target 2.5.

Both Jython and IronPython are good ways to *sneak in* Python into MS-only or Java-only shops, generally through their use for unittests.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's clear when to use IronPython or Jython. If you want to use Python on CLR/JVM, either as the main language or a scripting language for your C#/Java application.